# IceFaces ace:datatable: Need a selectall / select none buttons

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee-6, icefaces

I'm having a hell of a time adding a "select all" button to an icefaces datatable. I tried the following:

```
<h:commandButton
    value="Select All"
    actionListener="#{managedBeanMB.stateMap.setAllSelected(true)}" />
<h:commandButton
    value="Select None"
    actionListener="#{managedBeanMB.stateMap.setAllSelected(false)}" />
```

At best, this is inconsistent and unreliable. It also modifies the backing bean before the user submits the form.

the IceFaces javascript API doesn't seem to be any help either, as it only has a "clearSelection()" call, and I can't get that to work anyway.

Any help or ideas will be voted up... thanks!

Comment: Hmm, why don't you like to keep the selection state in a map? This is common practice. I wonder why you see it as inconsistent and unreliable?

Comment: ...there seems to be all sorts of small bugs in IceFaces that affect it. Sometimes the it works, sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes is stops working all together

Comment: Here's a specific complaint: Using the method I have in the outlined above, it will only select the visible items. Items that are in the paginator are not selected. With the craptastic auto-ajax "feature" of IceFaces, you can't force a UI refresh of the component on the page either.

Comment: Are you using the community or the enterprise edition of IceFaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We disabled paging... this seems to improve the buggy nature of IceFaces.